# Why is Kubuntu booting so slowly despite using an SSD?

Tags: boot, kubuntu, ssd

I recently switched from Windows 10 to Kubuntu 15.10 and I really like the possibility of customizing everything, but it's booting really slowly compared to Win10. There are also many cases where the system just freezes and many bugs can be found.

I'm aware that 15.10 is not LTS, but I was running Ubuntu on the latest version and never had any problems so I thought, I'd give Kubuntu a try.
Should I reinstall with the LTS version?

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your startup times, open your terminal using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and then enter the following:

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

That will give you a list of everything that started during the boot process and how long it took to start - before you entered userland.

If you want to see what's happening with the critical (system will not really work well without it) startup functions then user this:

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain
```

To get out of any of those menus and return to the terminal press <kbd>Q</kbd>.

systemd does a lot of things. If you're interested in learning more about systemd then try:

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain
```

Or, if you have a minute or three:

```
man systemd
```

Comment: When using systemd-analyze critical-chain I get some entries that are marked red. What does that mean?
What does man systemd do?

Comment: systemd-analyze critical-chain [UNIT...] prints a tree of the time-critical chain of units (for each of the specified UNITs or for the default target otherwise). The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character. The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character. Note that the output might be misleading as the initialization of one service might depend on socket activation and because of the parallel execution of units. (That's the man page information. Red is the +)